# I have HTML5 video in a lightbox. Why do multiple videos play and how do I stop them?

Tags: html, video, fancybox, mediaelement.js, fancybox-2

I have a Fancybox2 window popping up with the following code:

```
var mediaElementPlayers = [];

$("#video_list_widget a.video_link").fancybox({
    padding : 0,
    width:500,
    height: 360,
    closeBtn: false,
    content: '<video width="500" height="360" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" preload="auto">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://pathtomyvideo.mp4" />

    <source type="video/webm" src="http://pathtomyvideo.webm" />

</video>',
    afterShow: function() {
        var mediaElementPlayers = [];
        $('video,audio').each(function(){
            mediaElementPlayers.push(new MediaElementPlayer(this));
            console.log(mediaElementPlayers);
        });
    },

    beforeClose: function(){
        for (var i=0; i<mediaElementPlayers.length; i++){
            console.log(mediaElementPlayers);
            mediaElementPlayers[i].pause(); // pause
            mediaElementPlayers[i].setCurrentTime(0); // rewind
        }
        $('.fancybox-inner').empty();
    },
    afterClose: function (){
        $('video').remove();
    }


});
```

The first time I click the `a.video_link`, it pops up and plays just fine. Let's call this one Video 1. If I close the lightbox without stopping the video, it's stopped and killed. No problem.

If I click on the `a.video_link` again, it pops up and starts from the beginning (let's call this Video 2), but with the audio from Video 1 also playing over the top of it. If I now close Video 2's lightbox, the audio from Video 1 keeps playing. If I open the lightbox a third time, the audio from Video 2 also starts. This keeps going, so I can have lots of layers of audio over one another.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

**Update:** I can tell you that it doesn't occur when the autoplay attribute is removed, which suggests to me that the raw `<video>` object is playing before it can get wrapped in the mediaplayer js stuff. I'd really like the autoplay functionality if possible.

Comment: I don't know how relevant it would be for you but I just wrote a tutorial about how to play videos with mediaelement.js in fancyBox http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/ (I used only mp4 files though)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but I would imagine it is something to do with your selectors.

When you open/play a video it seems that it is also triggering the other ones on the page - I think the autoplay attribute is actually helping you by showing you that some of your code is targeting other players on the page that you don't want to mess with.

I would imagine it is this line that is the problem because it is acting globally on the page targeting all audio and video tags on the page, not just the audio/video tags within the specific element:

```
$('video,audio').each(function(){
```

I would change this line so it targets only specific audio/video tags - you could do this by giving the audio/video tags and id attribute or use jQuery to search - I don't have access to your code so this is probably won't work but it should be close to what you need:

```
$(this).find('video,audio').each(function(){
```

Hope this helps!